# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable in Django 1.10 Admin change_form.html {{ original|truncatewords:"18" }}

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I've had this a couple of times and not been able to debug  it. Last time I regressed code to my last checkin to avoid it but it remains a mystery.

Situation occurs when I use the standard admin app to view/edit my custom objects. I can see the objects listed in the view (in my case 
    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/athletes/totalsandstats/
where athletes is my app name, and TotalsAndStats is a model defined within athletes/models.py). When I click on one of the objects to try and view the details, I get the above exception.

Django Admin is trying to render the URL 
    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/athletes/totalsandstats/2/change/ 
using the template 
    /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_form.html

The error page states that the exception occurred at line 21 in the template, which is this:

```
&rsaquo; {% if add %}{% blocktrans with name=opts.verbose_name %}Add {{ name }}{% endblocktrans %}{% else %}{{ original|truncatewords:"18" }}{% endif %}
```

I see that

```
{{ original|truncatewords:"18" }}
```

is highlighted in red so I assume that "original" is not defined correctly. But I don't know what is the purpose of **original**, or how it relates to my model.

I suspect there must be some mismatch between my model and the way I have defined the corresponding admin model, but I can't see it. Perhaps would be helpful if I attach excerpt from the relevant files.

models.py

```
class TotalsAndStats(models.Model):
    # key will hold <athlete_id>:<period>
    athlete = models.ForeignKey(Athlete, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    period = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False)  # YYYY or 'All-time'
    time_retrieved = models.DateTimeField()
    rides = models.IntegerField()
    distance_km = models.FloatField()
    elevation_m = models.FloatField()
    hours = models.FloatField()

    @property
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.athlete.id) + ":" + self.period
```

admin.py

```
class TotalsAndStatsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['athlete', 'time_retrieved', 'period', 'rides', 'distance_km',
              'elevation_m', 'hours']
    list_filter = ['athlete']
    ordering = ['time_retrieved']
```

And full details of the exception:

```
TypeError at /admin/athletes/totalsandstats/2/change/

'str' object is not callable

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/athletes/totalsandstats/2/change/
Django Version:     1.10
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

'str' object is not callable

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py in force_text, line 76
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/python
Python Version:     3.4.5
Python Path:    

['/usr/src/app/StravaClub',
 '/usr/local/lib/python34.zip',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.4',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/plat-linux',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages',
 '/usr/src/app/StravaClub']

Server time:    Sun, 18 Dec 2016 18:14:45 +0000
```

Please help! :-)

Answer (score 1):

`@property` decorator isn't needed:

```
class TotalsAndStats(models.Model):

    # ...

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.athlete.id) + ":" + self.period
```